# Pegar "Nome da Versão" [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Tenho uma tela **Sobre** e gostaria de poder pegar o **Nome da Versão**, como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisamos utilizar o `DependencyService` para implementarmos o código para `Android` e para `iOS`.

Primeiramente iremos criar e definir nossa `Interface` que irá conter nosso método de retornar o nome da versão:

```
public interface IDevice
{
    string ConsultarVersao();
}
```

Agora criaremos uma classe no projeto `Android` e implementaremos nossa interface que no caso se chama `IDevice`:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MeuApp.Droid.DeviceDroid))]
namespace MeuApp.Droid
{
    public class DeviceDroid : IDevice
    {
        public string ConsultarVersao()
        {
            return Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName, 0).VersionName;
        }
    }
}
```

Agora faremos o mesmo para o `iOS`, criaremos uma classe no projeto `iOS` e implementaremos nossa interface `IDevice`:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MeuApp.iOS.DeviceIOS))]
namespace MeuApp.iOS
{
    public class DeviceIOS : IDevice
    {
        public string ConsultarVersao()
        {
            return NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleShortVersionString").ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Pronto, está tudo feito. Agora é só utilizar o método da seguinte forma que irá funcionar para ambas as plataformas:

```
DependencyService.Get<IDevice>().ConsultarVersao();
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o VersionTrack.

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

VersionTracking.Track();
```

> Após iniciar o Track, você poderá ler as informações de versão.

Abaixo os métodos:

```
// First time ever launched application
var firstLaunch = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver;

// First time launching current version
var firstLaunchCurrent = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchForCurrentVersion;

// First time launching current build
var firstLaunchBuild = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchForCurrentBuild;

// Current app version (2.0.0)
var currentVersion = VersionTracking.CurrentVersion;

// Current build (2)
var currentBuild = VersionTracking.CurrentBuild;

// Previous app version (1.0.0)
var previousVersion = VersionTracking.PreviousVersion;

// Previous app build (1)
var previousBuild = VersionTracking.PreviousBuild;

// First version of app installed (1.0.0)
var firstVersion = VersionTracking.FirstInstalledVersion;

// First build of app installed (1)
var firstBuild = VersionTracking.FirstInstalledBuild;

// List of versions installed (1.0.0, 2.0.0)
var versionHistory = VersionTracking.VersionHistory;

// List of builds installed (1, 2)
var buildHistory = VersionTracking.BuildHistory;
```

Fonte: [Xamarin.Essentials: Controle de versão](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking)

Comment: Tentei utilizar e não deu certo, mas agradeço, com a outra resposta consegui, agradeço.

Comment: Ok, Mesmo assim peço desculpas.

Comment: Não, agradeço pelo interesse em ajudar.